# C# Check if byte from Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes() is DEL

Tags: c#, unicode

I'm currently writing on a little chat program. However, I am using the `Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes()` now, but I noticed that I can't display all characters I want with it. So I want to change the `Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes()` function to the `Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes()` function since I can use more characters with it. However, for the program I need to check if a DEL is in an array of bytes. In ASCII DEL is represented as 127.
How is it with Unicode?

Comment: https://unicode-table.com

Comment: You should be checking for DEL *before* you convert the string to an array of bytes, surely?

Comment: @bassfader U+007F? How to check this in an array of bytes?

Comment: advice: use UTF-8, not Unicode (UTF-16); and `DEL` is still byte 127 in UTF-8, however frankly you may find it easier to decode first and check for `(char)127` instead

Comment: @MatthewWatson I add the DEL to a protocol before sending it away from the client so I can check where the protocol ends on the server.

Comment: @MarcGravell I need characters like ü, ä, ö and ß

Comment: "I need characters like ü, ä, ö and ß" : UTF-8 has access to all planes, and frankly UTF-8 *won the encoding wars*. You kinda need a good reason to choose anything other than UTF-8

Comment: @MarcGravell What are reasons to use not UTF-16 and use UTF-8?

Comment: @TomStrob good reasons to use UTF-16 might be a: perhaps if your storage is linked to text size - think "SQL Server": an `nvarchar(40)` is 40 characters, and being able to reserve 80 bytes is very convenient; b: if *almost all* of the text content is going to be in very high planes, but at that point you're getting into surrogate-pair territory, which means multiple UTF-16 code-points *anyway*, or c: if you're talking to Windows APIs *without decoding first*. None of these seem to apply here, so I'd 100% go UTF-8

Comment: @MarcGravell Ok, thanks! :)

Comment: @Evk Actually, in UTF8 leading bytes and continuation bytes do not share values, because a continuation byte always starts with "10" (in binary) and longer lead bytes begin with "11" - thus if you see an ASCII value in a UTF8 stream you know it's actually an ASCII character.

Comment: @MatthewWatson So in C# is a UTF8 characters always one byte?

Comment: @MatthewWatson indeed. Well, still good to avoid checking bytes I suppose, but decode first and check characters.

Comment: @TomStrob No, but ASCII characters are always one byte when encoded in UTF8. Non-ASCII characters tend to be encoded in 3 bytes in UTF8. [More details on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8).